# CRM.$ is not a function after upgrade 4.7.8 > 4.7.13

Tags: upgrade

Running upgrade CiviCRM 4.7.8 to 4.7.13, on Drupal 7, I have a white screen with just "[]" message and "Retry" and "Skip" buttons, and js error : CRM.$ is not a function.
Tried to change the theme : no effect.
js and css files are not compressed.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you run upgrade.php?

Comment: Also have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: When I run upgrade.php I have this error (after confirmation). And I have cleared the browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing the upgrade via drush if you are having trouble doing it in your browser.